# How do you update a large MySQL table that's on a server?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, import, update

I have an application on a web server.

The PHP front end for the application queries a MySQL database which has a table that contains 60 million taken domain names. My application queries this table to check if a domain name is available and it works surprisingly fast.

Every day, however, the list of taken domain names is updated by the organization which provides it.  I have to download the compressed new list of words and then use it to update the domains table for it to remain accurate.

I am not sure, however, how to go about updating the table which is live on the web MySQL server and takes up roughly 3 gigabytes.

I've researched it a bit, and the best so far I've found is to create a new table/database then delete the old one and switch them over. The changes to the table, however, are probably less than 1% daily, so this feels overkill and inefficient.

Would be great to know if there is a better way.

Comment: So why not dump the new data in a table and JOIN-UDPATE the existing one?

Comment: @David Gurevich What is the ENGINE and structure of the table? Which version of mysql are you using? In which format do you receive the list (is it ordered?).

Comment: @jynus The Engine is InnoDB.  The table consists of one column named domains which is the primary key and has the domain names in it as a string.  The list of domains is sorted alphabetically before I insert it.

The MySQL version is 5.5

As for the JOIN-UPDATE idea, it seems that would basically be the same as just creating a new table and switching, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the clarifications on your comment, I would recommend 2 options:

- Use `LOAD DATA INFILE IGNORE` to load the data directly from the filesystem. This will insert new domains and not touch the "old" ones, but **it will not delete the ones that are removed**. On the bright side, it will reduce IO a lot.
- Go for your approach: use `LOAD DATA INFILE` on a new table, then `RENAME` the old and new table, which is a very fast operation. Inserting on smaller tables is faster than inserting on larger tables on InnoDB, but the whole table has to be written.

In both cases, there are a lot of things that I can recommend you to improve the inserting performance.

If you do not perform other write operations than the import, **this would be one of the few cases in which I would recommend you to use MyISAM**- its import performance is faster, as it does not have to deal with a transaction log, and you will not have to deal with corruption, as you will only use it as a read-only table. If the import fails, you can always repeat it from the file.

If you use InnoDB, on the other side, you can **check for duplicates/missing records and modify them in parallel** to match MyISAM performance but that only will be performant on the latest MySQL versions (>= 5.6).

Other things to have into account: disable temporarily the binary log; disable keys, try fixed-with format (for MyISAM), disable the doublewrite buffer and autocommit, augment the buffer pool and transaction log, make sure you use `innodb_file_per_table=1` (for InnoDB). With proper tuning, for 5.5, I am able to insert a 50 million table (much wider than yours) in 2-3 minutes in MyISAM (without flushing the cache) and 11-12 minutes (durably) in InnoDB on spinning disks. 5.6 and 5.7 improved InnoDB performance closer to MyISAM.

**Addendum:** On other databases, I would recommend you to use a cursor to analyse the table row by row, but I do not have much faith on MySQL's programatic features.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that I can think of, if you have enough space on disk, is to do the pre-processing outside of the database.

You can use a [large-file comparison tool](https://superuser.com/questions/516289/tool-for-diffing-large-files) that do not require the files to be on memory (or even program your own quick script, I do not see it too complicated) and then generate a patch-like syntax, so you can, from that, generate a list of values to be `DELETE`d and `INSERT`d. If you presort the file before inserting it, you definitely can do that.